# GridFS retrieve only a range of a file using java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, gridfs

The docs mention that it is possible to retrieve a range of a document using gridFS. However I haven't found any more details about this. I would like to obtain a range of a file using the java driver for a grails app to support audio streaming. Do I need to get and assemble the packages manually in that case or is there any better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *skip* over the part of the file not needed and read only what you need from there.

```
    GridFSDBFile file = files.findOne("file");

    InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();

    long actuallySkipped = inputStream.skip(numberOfBytesToSkip);
    // read from here...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of that something like this would be possible, but I was wondering how that would actually perform. Is the java driver smart enough to just retrieve the bits from mongo that are actually used, or does this read the whole file into memory and just throw away the skipped bits?

Comment: If you take a look at the source for com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSDBFile.MyInputStream#skip (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/2.11.x/src/main/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFSDBFile.java#L164) you'll see all it does is update the current chunk, offset into that chunk and load that chunk. The earlier data never gets loaded... Pretty efficient.